# Null pointer exception using scribe oauth facebook

Tags: java, facebook, spring-mvc, oauth

Hello guys im trying to implement oauth 2.0 to get facebook access token with scribe and keep getting a null pointer exception. The line belows keeps getting a null pointer exception: 
`String authorizationUrl = oAuthService.getAuthorizaionUrl(Token.Empty())+"&"+STATE+"="+state;`

Below is my full code

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

private static final String STATE = "state";
private String client_id = "********";
private String app_secret = "********";
private String url = "http://localhost:8080";
private static final Token EMPTY_TOKEN = null;
private OAuthService oAuthService;
private FacebookClient obj; //passing the token to restfb object


public HomeController() {}


public HomeController(OAuthService oAuthService) {
    oAuthService = buildOAuthService(client_id, app_secret);
}

private OAuthService buildOAuthService(String client_id, String app_secret){
    return new ServiceBuilder()
            .provider(FacebookApi.class)
            .apiKey(client_id)
            .apiSecret(app_secret)
            .callback(url + "/auth/facebook/callback")
            .build();
     }
  @RequestMapping(value ="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String HomePage()
      {
   //home page and has the link to redirect to /auth/facebook
    return "login";
      }

//start the OAuth2 authorization flow
    @RequestMapping(value="/auth/facebook")
    public RedirectView startAuthentication(HttpSession httpSession) throws OAuthException {
         String state = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
         httpSession.setAttribute(STATE, state);
        //Below is where i'm having a null pointer exception
        String authorizationUrl = oAuthService.getAuthorizationUrl(Token.empty())+"&"+STATE+"="+state;
     return new RedirectView(authorizationUrl);
    }

   @RequestMapping(value="/auth/facebook/callback")
   public RedirectView callback(@RequestParam("code")String code, @RequestParam(STATE)String state, HttpSession httpsession) throws IOException
{
     String stateFromSession = (String)httpsession.getAttribute(STATE);
     if(!state.equals(stateFromSession)) {
        return new RedirectView("/login");
      }
    Token accessToken = getAccessToken(code);
    obj = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken.toString(), Version.VERSION_2_2);
    return new RedirectView("/loggedin");
   }
   private Token getAccessToken(String code) {
        Verifier verify = new Verifier(code);
        return oAuthService.getAccessToken(Token.empty(), verify);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your privately created object variable '*oAuthService*' is null.
Since we don't know the whole logic I'm assuming that this is the issue:

```
private OAuthService oAuthService;

public HomeController() {}

public HomeController(OAuthService oAuthService) {
    oAuthService = buildOAuthService(client_id, app_secret);
}
```

If you change the last constructor to:

```
public HomeController(OAuthService oAuthService) {
        this.oAuthService = buildOAuthService(client_id, app_secret);
    }
```

or

```
public HomeController(OAuthService oAuthService) {
        this.oAuthService = oAuthService;
    }
```

it will work.

Edit:
Nice post about the use of '*this*' can be found here: http://javapapers.com/core-java/explain-the-java-this-keyword/